# Springboot run failing on Eureka client dependency

Tags: java, netflix-eureka

When I add this to my project parent pom:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

the project run fails like this:

```
    2019-11-11 00:12:56.158  INFO 78547 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
    2019-11-11 00:12:56.421  INFO 78547 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$684316fc] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2019-11-11 00:12:56.436  WARN 78547 --- [  restartedMain] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bootstrapImportSelectorConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationPropertiesBean
    2019-11-11 00:12:56.466  INFO 78547 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-11-11 00:12:56.483 ERROR 78547 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bootstrapImportSelectorConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationPropertiesBean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:743) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:390) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:206) [spring-cloud-context-2.2.0.RC1.jar:2.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:117) [spring-cloud-context-2.2.0.RC1.jar:2.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:74) [spring-cloud-context-2.2.0.RC1.jar:2.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) [spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) [spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) [spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127) [spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:76) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:341) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at com.iutr.infoaggrplf.Application.main(Application.java:23) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationPropertiesBean
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBeans.java:94) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.0.RC1.jar:2.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:414) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBean
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    ... 33 common frames omitted

2019-11-11 00:12:56.486 ERROR 78547 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bootstrapImportSelectorConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationPropertiesBean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:743) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:390) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:206) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.0.RC1.jar:2.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:117) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.0.RC1.jar:2.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:74) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.0.RC1.jar:2.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:76) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:341) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at com.iutr.infoaggrplf.Application.main(Application.java:23) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationPropertiesBean
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBeans.java:94) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.0.RC1.jar:2.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:414) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBean
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

When I remove the dependency, the project runs successfully.

I'm just trying to add a Eureka client to register center but it doesn't work. When I create a new project with Spring Initializr though, it works well.

Every answer helps.

The full project `pom.xml` is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.iutr.application</groupId>
  <artifactId>infoaggrplf-all</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <modules>
    <module>infoaggrplf.app</module>
    <module>infoaggrplf.service</module>
    <module>infoaggrplf.api</module>
    <module>infoaggrplf.service.impl</module>
  </modules>

  <parent>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <relativePath/>
    <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.RC1</spring-cloud.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.iutr.shared</groupId>
      <artifactId>member-service</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.iutr.shared</groupId>
      <artifactId>member-service-impl</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--热部署-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>spring-milestones</id>
      <name>Spring Milestones</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>


</project>
```

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58649574/eureka-server-while-starting-in-spring-boot-getting-the-errors

Answer (score 15):

Try with version of spring boot : 2.2.2 as shown below

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

This class is available since 2.2.0.Please refer below link

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationPropertiesBean.html

Comment: YES! This did it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 10):

This is a common Spring Boot <-> Spring Cloud version compatibility mismatch problem. Have a look at the `Table 1. Release train Spring Boot compatibility` section at [spring.io/projects/spring-cloud](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud):

```
Spring Cloud            <-> Spring Boot    

2020.0.x (aka Ilford)   <-> 2.4.x

Hoxton                  <-> 2.2.x, 2.3.x (Starting with SR5)

Greenwich               <-> 2.1.x

Finchley                <-> 2.0.x
```

Also see the complete list of all the [`spring-cloud-dependencies` versions at Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies).

So in your case using Spring Boot `2.1.7.RELEASE`, make sure to also use a `Greenwich.SRx` release (this is why Said Dekkaki`s answer works):

```
  <properties>
    <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR6</spring-cloud.version>
  </properties>
```

Or better: upgrade to a newer Spring Boot version (as Neeush Sreenivas suggested):

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Or even better: **Use both the most current versions** - as of writing: `spring-boot-starter-parent` with `2.4.1` and `spring-cloud-dependencies` with `2020.0.0`.

Answer (score 4):

change your Spring Cloud version from Hoxton.RC1 to  Greenwich.SR1 in your XML

Comment: While not marked as accepted, the OP verified that @Neeush-Sreenivas’s answer from six months ago solved the problem.

Comment: @Said Dekakki, Thanks for the post. It worked for e even am using the parent pom version 2.1.3. Anyways thank you once again for sharing this.